# Visual Basic - Referencing a combobox with a variable in name

Tags: vba, variables, combobox

I'm attempting to create a for loop that cycles through each combobox within my form and checking if the selection is unique or not. I'm not sure about how to select a combobox using a variable within the name.

This is what I have right now, but it doesn't work at all.

```
    For x As Integer = 1 To 4
        ComboBox & x.SelectedValue
    Next
```

Comment: It may be useful to have more details here.  I'm not clear on what the code example in the question is trying to do...  Are the `ComboBox`es called `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2`, etc.?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't include this before. Yes, I am using ComboBox1, ComboxBox2 naming.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Controls` collection of the `Form` (`Me`)

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 4
      MsgBox Me.Controls("ComboBox" & x).Name
    Next
End Sub
```